# Laravel route function in db seeder file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, seeding

I am trying to get url from a named route. When I call the method in header file

```
<a href="{{route('cmsPage', 'thematic_areas')}}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown">Thematic Areas<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

The result is correct

```
http://hassaan.discover.local/page/thematic_areas
```

Whereas when the same method is called in db seeder file

```
AdminNavBar::create(array('name'=>'Thematic Area', 'link'=>route('cmsPage', 'thematic_areas'), 'parent_id'=>'0'));
```

The result is incorrect. (URL which is stored in db after running seed from php artisan)

```
http://localhost/page/thematic_areas
```

I cannot figure out why the base URL becomes different in seeding

Comment: what's the url in your config/app.php ?

Comment: It was set to localhost actually. Now I have changed it and working perfectly. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like artisan is picking up a different environment config to your webserver. The url setting in config/app.php defaults to `http://localhost`.

try using the `--env=local` (or whatever the correct environment is) flag when you call artisan db:seed

Comment: That might not be a problem with the environment at all. On the CLI superglobals like `$_SERVER` are not available, therefore it's hard to dynamically resolve URLs automatically. That's why the Application URL has to be set manually for CLI tasks.

Comment: The route method uses the config settings to get that URL, not superglobals. It's more likely there is a config/local/app.php with the correct domain, but the config/app.php hasn't been updated. By default artisan uses the production configuration.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for clarification. It was just a guess, I did not take a look on the route method. Good answer so far!

Comment: I just happen to have gone through the URL helper methods before - it was quite a rabbit hole haha

Comment: Thanks judereid!. You were right the config/app.php hasn't been updated. Now the db:seed is working perfectly find after updating.