# Laravel 5.5: route() function in seeder returns wrong route (localhost/ not localhost:8000/)

Tags: php, laravel

In my seeder I have this:

```
'route' => route('home') // should return http://localhost:8000
```

However it returns `http://localhost`

I have this problem only in my seeder. Using `route('home')` anywhere else will return `http://localhost:8000`. How can I get the correct route in my seeder?
I found the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796023/laravel-route-function-in-db-seeder-file) posted a few year back although it doesn't work for Laravel 5.5.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the following line in your .env file: `APP_URL=http://localhost` to `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` and then run `php artisan config:cache` in case it's necessary